# getting total no of viewers in php 

Tags: php

Im developing a site, i want to know how can i track who has viewed the profile of particular users, registered users or visiters. Site is developed in php.

Any sugesstion please.

Comment: Any reason you can't use Google Analytics?  http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: I suggest you accept more answers to your questions.

Comment: @Mark He's likely looking for a "live" solution. I smell a forum being developed.

Comment: @Mark Biek: potential privacy concerns aside, GA doesn't have your session data by default... and it might become unwieldy if you have tons of specific profiles you want to watch. Apart from that, it isn't capable of tracking user agents that don't support (or enable) JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I've understood something wrong, but it seems to be something like this.

Em... First question, I think should be asked - all of pages visitors are definitely aut.? (I mean, is it necessary to authorization to get this profile data).

So, if all of them are definitely aut., you can just take something, defines this user (id or something else) and add it to special field of this profiles DB record (or anywhere else).

Or you can add (for example if you have to remember 10 last visits) 10 fields and a kind of "first pointer" - a number which tells you from which of this field you should start (like this:

... | 1rv | 2rv | 3rv | 4rv | 5rv | 6rv | fp |

234 432 432 432 32 234  5

if means, you should start from 5th - show contents of 5rv 6rv 1rv 2rv 3rv 4rv 5rv 6rv

and when something changes you just fp++, and write to fp's field...

It should work really good with mass of data, I think...

PS or you can inc. performance by crating an every user's pattern of "visit" message - I mean: you have feild "how message of my visit 'd look like", you just paste where you need it...

Answer (score 1):

Thats a very broad question... With lack of specifics something like this:

- Store the user_id in a session
  variable
- Everytime a user goes
  to a profile page update the
  appropriate related record to the
  profile with the user_id from the
  session.

Answer (score 1):

Well, whenever you generate a page that you want to track stuff for, collect whatever you need from `$_SERVER`, `$_SESSION` etc. and append it to a database table or something like that. You can then write a fancy analysis tool that creates awesome statistics from that data, or whatever else you wanted to use the data for.